# Unable to save trigger logic in apex class

Tags: apex, trigger, class

I have wrote trigger and I am trying to implement the same in apex class. When I wrote a method and saved the logic. I am getting Illegal assignment error.

Below piece of code, I am trying to place in apex class.

Trigger:

```
trigger UserTrigger on User ( before update) {
    UserTriggerHandler.delegatedapprover(Trigger.new, Trigger.oldmap);
}
```

Class:

```
public without sharing class UserTriggerHandler2 {

    public static void delegatedapprover(List<User> newlist, Map<Id,User> oldmap){
        Id profileId = userinfo.getProfileId();
        String profileName=[Select Id,Name from Profile where Id=:profileId].Name;

        for( User u : newlist) {    
            if(ProfileName ==  'Contact Manager') {
                User oldUser = oldmap.get(u.Id);
                //if(oldUser.DelegatedApproverId != null){
                    if(oldUser.DelegatedApproverId != u.DelegatedApproverId) {
                        u.addError('error message');
                    }
                //}
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Ideally you should pass new and old list/map from trigger to handler class method. Where is `newlist` defined in apex class?

Answer (score 2):

Since `Trigger.oldMap` has no reference in the class, its returning a SObject instead of User.

However, since you have already taken the oldMap as input from the trigger, you can use the same variable on line 10.

```
User oldUser = oldMap.get(u.Id);
```

And you call the method from the trigger like this:

```
UserTriggerHandler.delegatedapprover(Trigger.new, Trigger.oldMap);
```